# Existence of a element in the dual of $\ell^\infty$

Tags: functional-analysis

I'm trying to prove this:

we know that $T:C([0,1])\to \ell^\infty$ is a linear isometry. Find $u\in(\ell^\infty)^*$ such that $||u||=1$ and $u(Tf)=\int_0^1 f(t)dt$.

My first attempt is define $u:\ell^\infty\to \mathbb{R}$ as we wish, but this would only be possible if T is surjective.

Any hint or help is welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: Define $u(Tf)=\int_0^{1} f(t)dt$. This is well defined (because $T$ is injective) and it is bounded because $\|Tf||=\|f\|$ and $|\int_0^{1} f(t)dt| \leq \|f\|$. Apply Hahn-Banach Theorem to extend $u$ to a continuous linear functional on $\ell^{\infty}$.